# difference between VM_IO and VM_RESERVED

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory

What is the difference between the vma_flags `VM_IO` and `VM_RESERVED`? How should they be used?
The comments in linux kernel source code is very confusing

> http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mm.h?v=3.4;a=arm#L104
>   http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mm.h?v=3.4;a=arm#L96

```
#define VM_IO           0x00004000      /* Memory mapped I/O or similar */
#define VM_RESERVED     0x00080000      /* Count as reserved_vm like IO */
```

Thanks

Comment: How do I change the font size? I copied text from somewhere else it shows like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From:  http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-1

"`VM_IO` marks a VMA as being a memory-mapped I/O region. Among other things, the VM_IO flag prevents the region from being included in process core dumps.
`VM_RESERVED` tells the memory management system not to attempt to swap out this VMA; it should be set in most device mappings."

For better understanding of how and why these evolved and what is the linux kernel community's recommendation, read these lwn articles:

http://lwn.net/Articles/161204/
http://lwn.net/Articles/162860/

---

**UPDATE:**
The `VM_RESERVED` flag has been discontinued. See Linus' [patch](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=547b1e81afe3119f7daf702cc03b158495535a25)

Comment: Great answer, many thanks!

The problem I want to solve is to find the virtual memory area of a process that is mapped for DMA (Direct Memory Access). VM_RESERVED seems to be the closest flag that suggests such use? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I am not sure, not an expert on the topic :). You are better off browsing the linux kernel source code and documentation, that's your safest bet!